# Почему не отображаются с первого раза значения переменной сохраненные через юзердефолт?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

При воспроизведении таймера, значения измененные через UIStepper и сохраненные в другом контроллере начинаются с дефолтного значения переменной, а после первого прокручивания таймера начиется отображаться уже с нужными измененными значениями

1 контроллер:

```
var duretionExersise = 30.0 // дефолтное значение переменной вынесено за класс контроллера

@IBOutlet weak var secondsStepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var secondsLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("duretionExersise") != nil  { 
        duretionExersise = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("duretionExersise") as! Double
    }
    secondsStepper.value = duretionExersise
    secondsStepper.minimumValue = 1
    secondsStepper.maximumValue = 60
}

@IBAction func secondsStepper(sender: UIStepper) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Int(sender.value), forKey: "duretionExersise")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    secondsLabel.text = "\(Int(sender.value).description) seconds"
}
```

2 контроллер

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("duretionExersise") != nil  { 
        duretionExersise = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("duretionExersise") as! Double
    }
    //Есть лэйбл в нем отображаем начальное значение таймера
    timerLabel.text = "\(Int(duretionExersise))"
}

var timer = NSTimer()
var exersiseTime = Int(duretionExersise)
var timerRunning = false
var i = 0


func Counting(){
    exersiseTime -= 1
    timerLabelChange.text = "\(Int(exersiseTime))"

    if exersiseTime == -1 {
        i += 1
        exersiseTime = Int(duretionExersise)
        timerLabelChange.text = "\(Int(exersiseTime))"
}

@IBAction func closeButton(sender: UIButton) {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Counting"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            timerRunning = true

}
```

Comment: После сохранения значения в `NSUserDefaults` Вам необходимо сделать следующее: `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()`

Comment: Почему то на симуляторе правильно работает только если перед запуском таймера просто зайти на 1 контроллер, не меняя ничего, а если при запуске в симуляторе сразу зайти на контроллер с таймером и запустить, то ошибка остается

Comment: ваш код вставил так:      @IBAction func secondsStepper(sender: UIStepper) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Int(sender.value), forKey: "duretionExersise")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()                                       
               secondsLabel.text = "\(Int(sender.value).description) seconds"
}

Comment: Есть такая проблема с симулятором, когда synchronize происходит не мгновенно, а с задержкой до 10 секунд. попробуйте воспроизвести на девайсе, либо после сохранения подождать несколько секунд перед загрузкой.

Comment: К сожелению не помогло даже на девайся и подождать тож не помогло, при новом запуске аппа и заходе сразу в таймер ошибка осталась

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Упустил необходимость переопределить переменную exersiseTime в методе viewDidLoad(). Во 2 контроллер в viewDidLoad() необходимо добавить `exersiseTime = Int(duretionExersise)`